# Can not Import 'document' from Pyscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, pyscript

According to pyscript documentation, there is an object called 'document' in pyscript which I can not import from.

```
from pyscript import document
```

and the error I get is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'document' from 'pyscript' (c:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscript\__init__.py)
```

and when I look into **init**.py;

```
"""A CLI for PyScript!"""
import json
from pathlib import Path

import platformdirs
from rich.console import Console

APPNAME = "pyscript"
APPAUTHOR = "python"
DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILENAME = "pyscript.json"


# Default initial data for the command line.
DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    # Name of config file for PyScript projects.
    "project_config_filename": "manifest.json",
}


DATA_DIR = Path(platformdirs.user_data_dir(appname=APPNAME, appauthor=APPAUTHOR))
CONFIG_FILE = DATA_DIR / Path(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILENAME)
if not CONFIG_FILE.is_file():
    DATA_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with CONFIG_FILE.open("w") as config_file:
        json.dump(DEFAULT_CONFIG, config_file)


try:
    from importlib import metadata
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    import importlib_metadata as metadata  # type: ignore


try:
    import rich_click.typer as typer
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    import typer  # type: ignore


try:
    __version__ = metadata.version("pyscript")
except metadata.PackageNotFoundError:  # pragma: no cover
    __version__ = "unknown"


console = Console()
app = typer.Typer(add_completion=False)
with CONFIG_FILE.open() as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
```

I don't know how to fix it, what to do?

Since its and import error, I checked root folder and all I saw was 2-3 functions named 'cli', '_generate' etc.

Comment: what version of `pyscript` do you use? The newest version has some changes and older code may not work.

Comment: did you try to use `document` without importing it? Why do you want to import it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you installed `pyscript-cli` not `pyscript`. `pyscript-cli` is to

> Quickly wrap Python scripts into a HTML template, pre-configured with PyScript.

It is not the tool for developing pyscript-specific code itself.

Secondly, regarding installation of `pyscript`, here is what the [documentation](https://pyscript.net/) has to say:

> Just kidding, you don't need to install anything.

`pyscript` is to be run exclusively on a web browser with a special Python interpreter. You are not supposed to either install `pyscript` locally or run a script containing pyscript-specific code locally. Therefore, the behavior that you cannot do `from pyscript import document` with your local Python is expected.

In the browser, a Python interpreter is loaded from a specific source (copied from [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/2023.09.1.RC2/user-guide/#first-steps))

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/snapshots/2023.09.1.RC2/core.css">
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/snapshots/2023.09.1.RC2/core.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then you point to the loaded interpreter which script to run and what config to follow (copied from [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/2023.09.1.RC2/user-guide/#file-or-inline))

```
<script type="py" src="main.py" config="pyscript.toml"></script>
```

You develop the Python script over the browser (i.e., observe the behavior and output of the script), not over your local interpreter.

Comment: A great answer! But to correct one thing - at time of writing, `/latest` doesn't point to the right version either. The better link would be `https://pyscript.net/snapshots/2023.09.1.RC2/core.js`

Comment: Thanks @JeffGlass, the link is updated.